# Angular distance from radius of sphere and distance along circumference

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

How can I calculate the angular distance between 2 points on the circumference of a circle with only the distance along the circumference between the 2 points and the radius of the circle? I spent some time looking for the answer on how to do this but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: $\Delta L = r \Delta \alpha$

Comment: So 'angular distance' means the same as angle, right? You have two points along the circumference of a circle. You know the radius of the circle and the distance of the points along the circumference of the circle. How about you imagine the other way around: If you have a circle with a known radius, and you have an internal angle, what is the distance along the circumference of the circle that the angle corresponds to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea: You know how far you have to go if you have to go around the *whole* circle (that's the circumference). That corresponds to $360^\circ$. Now consider how much of the circumference you're using. That corresponds to whatever the angle is.

Comment: Would this be correct? $\frac{d}{2\pi r}*360$

Comment: @TrueCP5 Looks good to me. Assuming you want your angles in degrees, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you measure the central angle of an arc of a circle in radians, and if the angle measures $\phi$ and the arc $s,$ then they are related by the equation $$s=r\phi,$$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle.

This just says that the arc is directly proportional to the angle. If you're measuring your angles in $\theta$ degrees, note that we have $\phi=\frac{π\theta}{180°}.$